# vb .net swallow ICloneable implementation

Tags: vb.net, implementation, icloneable

I know there's tons of question on the matter. But I couldn't, for the life of me, make any sense of the answers or use them in my example. I am newish in vb .net and I can't really implement general examples to my specific one. What I have is basically this:

```
dim a as New list(of player)
EDIT: dim b as New list(of player)    'previously was: dim b as new player

Class player
    Public name As String
    '[more]
End Class
```

[....]

```
a.Add(New player)
b.Add(New player)
a(0).name="john"
b=a
a(0).name="jack"
msgbox(b(0).name) 'it will print jack instead of john
```

I now this can be done with ICloneable, but after reading up a lot on it I can't implement correctly.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Like C#, assignment in VB.NET does _not_ copy/clone/duplicate an object. Both `a` and `b` _refer to the same object_ after the assignment. That is, the variables refer to the same collection, and the first element is also (implicitly) the same Player..

Comment: The desired behavior might be to “clone all objects in a collection”, although its not entirely clear which part of the shared-object-mutability is an issue.

Comment: It makes no sense to make `b=a`. a is a list of players and b is a player. Did you mean `b = a(0)`?

Comment: @Mary it's my bad. Both a and b are lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `a(0)` to `b` they are both pointing to the same object in memory. Even though you declared `b` as `New player` that new player was thrown away when you made the assignment to an existing player.

To prove this to yourself, try the opposite. Change the `name` property of `b` and you will see it is reflected in the `name` property of `a(0)`.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim a As New List(Of player)
    Dim b As player
    a.Add(New player)
    a(0).name = "john"
    b = a(0)
    b.name = "jack"
    MsgBox(a(0).name) 'jack
End Sub
```

Now to Clone...

```
Class player
    Implements ICloneable
    Public name As String
    '[more]
    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Dim p As New player
        p.name = name
        Return p
    End Function
End Class
```

Your class now implements `ICloneable` with the addition of the `Clone` function. You can implement this however you wish as long as the signature of the function matches the interface signature for the `Clone` method.

Notice that my implementation is creating a `New` player and is assigning the `name` property to the `name` of the existing player. This New player is what is returned by the function. The New player will have a different location in memory so changes to the first player from the list and this new player will not affect each other.

Since the `Clone` function returns an object, we need to cast it to `player` (the underlying type) so it will match our declare of `b` and we will be able to use the properties and methods of the `player` class.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim a As New List(Of player)
    Dim b As player
    a.Add(New player)
    a(0).name = "john"
    b = CType(a(0).Clone, player)
    a(0).name = "jack"
    MsgBox(b.name) 'john
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

To accomplish your goal using 2 lists, I created a new class called `PlayerList`. It inherits `List(Of Player)` and implements `ICloneable`. You can now clone list `a` and get completely separate lists with composed of separate player objects.

```
Public Class PlayerList
    Inherits List(Of player)
    Implements ICloneable
    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Dim newList As New PlayerList
        For Each p As player In Me
            Dim newP = CType(p.Clone(), player)
            newList.Add(newP)
        Next
        Return newList
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim a As New PlayerList()
    Dim b As PlayerList
    a.Add(New player)
    a(0).name = "john"
    b = CType(a.Clone, PlayerList)
    a(0).name = "jack"
    MsgBox(b(0).name)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems like I had it almost right, but there were some things that I had wrong, but now it all makes more sense to me and it works as intended.

I wonder then, can you do `b=a.clone` ? Where both a and b are `lists of player` or it's just easier to put it in a loop, `b(i)=a(i).clone`?

Comment: @Monochromatic You can't do `b = a.Clone` because `List(Of T)` does not implement `ICloneable`.  If, however, `a` was an instance of a type that did itself implement `ICloneable`, you could do that.

Comment: @Monochromatic Please see the EDIT portion of my answer.